# What is a good metric for the distance between two collections of unordered sets of any size?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

1. There are unordered sets of unfixed length containing independent categorical elements.
   (In the real world scenario, elements may possess similarity, but I am ignoring that, for now, to keep the problem simple.)
2. There are unordered collections (sets) of these sets.

What is a way I might define the distances between any two of these collections?

I prefer distance metrics that fit the normal rules for a valid distance metric. I would like to consider that sets in different collections that are not identical but share some common elements possess some influence to reduce the distance compared to if no elements were the same, otherwise, the distance between such collections would be the same as the distances between the sets.

Thoughts:
I have considered matching similar sets to each other and taking an average or total distance between the pairs, plus some distance for any leftover sets if the collections have an uneven number of sets, but I do not like the problems that come from a greedy algorithm and I dislike the computation cost that comes from a more sophisticated pairing.
I realize that comparing every set in collection A with every set in collection B requires some sort of adjustment so that large, but very similar collections do not receive a large distance simply because every possible pair of sets that do not match well add up to a large distance.

Comment: One possibility is to consider each collection as a multiset: count how many times a given element appears in any of the sets in a collection, and use those counts to define a metric.